# opendolphin to keep 3000 objects syncronized to the clients

Tags: java, postgresql, applet, javafx-8, opendolphin

I have an JavaFX standalone application in a server PC doing the following:

Take data from some serial devices (rs232) each 200ms and save that data in a postgresql database. That size of the data is up to 2500 objects with 15 fields (2500 rows with 15 columns in database)

Also, i have others Javafx applications (clients) in the Local Area Network that take that data from the server database each 500 ms, and display them in a JavaFX GUI.

My question is: Can i use Open Dolphin to keep all those objects synchronized in all the clients? (taking in account the sampling time requierement and the amount of data).

I have been reading about OpenDolphin, but the examples that i saw are with Strings synchronization, without time pressure.

PD: If not, which one technique would be?

Thanks

Comment: An applet? Where from? And what are the clients?

Comment: The clients applets are in the same local area network than the server applet. Thank you.

Comment: And those applets are what exactly? Don't tell me you mean actual Java applets? Don't use them in 2015; at least use JNLP instead

Comment: Yeap is a standalone JavaFX application. I did not use the explorer.

Comment: Well, uh, use a ScheduledExecutorService... But I also have another solution

Comment: Isn't "an applet in a server" an oxymoron? An applet runs in a browser, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is directly extracted from a class of mine and you gave me an idea, so I'll just implement it; the class is [here](https://github.com/fge/grappa-debugger/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/grappa/debugger/common/GuiTaskRunner.java).

What I intend to do following your question is to replace the `ExecutorService` which is currently there by a `ScheduledExecutorService` and implement the method below; note that the `@OnBackgroundThread` and `@OnUiThread` are "just" regular, `@Documented` annotations which I use:

```
public <T> void computeFixedDelay(
    @OnBackgroundThread final Supplier<? extends T> supplier,
    @OnUiThread final Consumer<? super T> consumer,
    final long quantity, final TimeUnit unit)
{
    backgroundExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        final T value = supplier.get();
        frontendExecutor.execute(() -> consumer.accept(t));
    }, 0L, quantity, unit);
}
```

Feel free to copy the task and implement the suggestion then add this method. You will then be able to do this in your JavaFX clients by initializing an instance of this class (pass `Platform::runLater` as the second argument).

Below it is assumed that:

- `db::task` is what gets the data from the database;
- `ui::update` takes that data and updates the GUI.

You can then do:

```
taskRunner.computeFixedDelay(db::task, ui::update, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: That is a good technique, but i am waiting for some Open Dolphin users comments. At this moment, i am doing something like that with databases connection. Thank you for you answer, if nobody says something about open dolphin experience i will accept your answer.

Comment: Well, if it does not fit your needs, you don't have to ;) And uh, I use MVP, so I don't use opendolphin